# How do you say to someone that you will reuse a sentence you've just heard from them?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

How do you say to someone that you will reuse a sentence (or a joke) you've just heard from them, as-is, because you liked it a lot ?

In Italian we say *"Questa me la rivendo"*, that translated is *"I'm gonna resell that one"* 
(***ri-vendo*** / ***re-sell*** is the idiomatic part, the other words could be recombined / replaced).

I can't find anything in the web, so... what is the English version ?

Comment: I tell folks who post terrific one-liners here that "I'm gonna steal that".

Comment: To steal: To present or use (someone else's words or ideas) as one's own. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/steal

Comment: @AndreaLigios I'm gonna steal "that one;" I wanna use "that one."

Comment: @Elian: I've edited the question accordingly (*I'm gonna* instead of *I will*, *that one* instead of *this*), to leave "wrong" only the subject of the question

Comment: "Appropriate" used as a verb is fun.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When I hear a phrase I admire, I generally say "I want to use that" or "I'm gonna ***[steal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/steal)*** that" as well.

> - To present or use (someone else's words or ideas) as one's own. (AHD)

Comment: So Andrea is going to steal "going to steal"?

Comment: @Kevin no, he has paid Emerald 15 reps. Fair trade.

Comment: If someone said `I want to use that` to me in that context I would think they are either weird or not a native speaker.

Comment: This is how I've normally heard it, too "That's a great phrase, I'm stealing that", although "Borrowing" in the same context does work too.

Answer (score 20):

Another alternative is "I'm borrowing that phrase!":

> I'm not sure how I do that, but you better believe **I'm borrowing that phrase**. It's great!

([A comment](http://www.knowingthedifference.com/2009/01/unapologetically-embracing-myself.html) on the phrase "unapologetically embracing myself")

> God-awful nose bender
>   **I'm borrowing that phrase**. It's perfect!

([reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/stopsmoking/comments/2v8c00/dat_smell_doe/))

On a similar note, when you later actually use a borrowed expression, you can  introduce it with **"to borrow a phrase"**:

> **To borrow a phrase**, if you can't stand the heat get out of the kitchen.

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/borrow))

> **To borrow a phrase from my mother**, I spend too much time “watching the boob tube” and not enough time outside.

([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phrase))

Comment: Yes, that is on the top with "to steal". We have this form too... So in Italian we have the equivalent of borrowing, stealing and reselling, while you've only the first two, for what I've got until now

Comment: I disagree that "To borrow a phrase" would be used when repeating a phrase you've earlier said you would "borrow" - counterintuitive, perhaps, but "To borrow a phrase" really means "I'm quoting someone else" or "I'm repeating a metaphor" rather than "I've stolen this idiom/phrasing"

Comment: @JonStory Jon, I think you misread my answer. I never said "to borrow a phrase" introduces what you yourself said earlier. Yes, it basically means you're quoting someone else. And that's what my answer says.

Answer (score 11):

You can tell them that you intend to [quote](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quote) them.

> quote  verb
>
> : to repeat (something written or said by another person) exactly
>
> : to write or say the exact words of (someone)
>
> : to write or say a line or short section from (a piece of writing or a speech)

Comment: This is the literal answer, but I think the OP was asking for the idiomatic answer as suggested by @Josh61 and included in the answer by  Emerald Ware "to steal"

Answer (score 7):

> This one's going straight into my armory/toolbox/collection/phrasebook.

The actually idiomatic part here is "this one" as an immediate reference to a recognizably iconic utterance.  The rest is more or less made up but complements the idiom "straight out of the book".

Answer (score 4):

I would say:

> I am so gonna use that.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm claiming that one for myself!

This suggests that not only will you use the phrase/sentence in question yourself but you think so highly of it you are prepared to pretend you thought of it first and will claim that to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider saying:

> Do you mind if I quote you (on that)?
>   I would like to (want to) quote you (on that).

The verb [quote](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quote) with an object means:

> Repeat or copy out (words from a text or speech written or ***spoken
>   by another person***): *I realized she was quoting passages from Shakespeare*

It is a little more formal than "I am going to steal that" but broadly used.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: This implies that attribution may be involved, which changes the meaning quite significantly. It doesn't mean you're going to use the phrase yourself, but that you're going to tell other people that the original speaker used it.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​hony: If you mean A.P.'s answer, it's different in the way that I literally just explained.

Comment: The order in which answers are presented (a) is user-configurable, and (b) changes over time. Please refer to answers by author and/or direct HTTP link. If you're referring to James's answer, then yours does _not_ differ from it (never claimed it did), and I downvoted that one too.

Answer (score 1):

> I am going to use that

or

> I am going to steal that

are the ones most commonly heard.

Answer (score 0):

A well-known idiomatic usage for this context (definition from [Cambridge dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pass-sth-on)) is...

> **pass it on** *- to ​tell someone something that another ​person has told you*

...which is commonly used in respect of "relaying, repeating" *information, jokes, quotes,* etc.

If what's being passed on is something *physical* there's often the implication that the original owner/user no longer needs it (outgrown clothing, upgraded technological gadgets, etc.). Unsurprisingly, it can thus have the negative connotations of BrE [**cast-offs**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cast-offs) in such contexts.

But when passing on a *copy* (of information, jokes, etc.), the connotations are invariably positive (whatever is is, it's something you want to spread around, because you think it's *good*).

Comment: I guess the difference is that when you use this, there's a reference to the source, while when "stealing that one" you are going to use it anonimously, like if it was your

Comment: @Andrea Ligios: Absolutely. I don't claim that my point here about the different connotations of "passing on" a single physical object or a *copy* is some kind of groundbreaking new perspective. But if someone said they were going to *steal* it, I'd assume they intended to ***pass it off*** as their own, rather than simply spread it to a wider audience (with or without explicit attribution to me as the source). *Passing on* (dying) isn't exactly desirable, but having your words/ideas passed on (copied, repeated) to others (perhaps even after your death) is usually seen as a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

"I'll quote you on that" implies that you will name the originator and hold them responsible.  "I'll pass that along" is a common and friendly form.
"I'll echo that" is short, and implies agreement.  The same is true for "I'll copy that", but it might be misunderstood literally.

Comment: I like *I'll echo that*! On the other hand, I can use *copy that* only when wearing the Jack Bauer's t-shirt :P

Comment: @AndreaLigios: "I'll echo that" means "I agree", not "I will use that phrase myself in the future". Hence I don't think it is relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I say

> That goes in the lexicon!